# PHPUnit version does not match version in Composer

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I'm trying to update my **phpunit** version, however it doesn't seem to be working with the regular `composer install`.

My composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "require": {
        ...
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "^1.1",
        "phpunit/dbunit": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

And running both composer `install` and `update` as `php composer.phar install` and `php composer.phar update` (I don't have composer installed globally which might be the issue?) I get

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
```

When I check to see the phpunit version, I get

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

My PHP version is 5.6 which does seem to rule out the solution from [this very similar issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6238).

My best guess is that there is a global version of **phpunit** installed and overriding my local one. But I haven't been able to find any guidance as to how to fix this without making too many changes to the rest of the global environment.

Comment: Yes, you've got a global `phpunit` installed, which you'd have to upgrade outside of your repo/Composer. The one installed by Composer lives at `vendor/bin/phpunit` (which you can use directly, if you like).

Comment: @ceejayoz So is there a way to run the local version of `phpunit` instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, just use `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of `phpunit` in your commands (presuming you're already `cd`ed into the repository). `vendor/bin/phpunit --version` etc.

Comment: Got it. I ran into a small permissions issue for `/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` where I couldn't execute from `vendor/bin/phpunit`, but after adjusting those permissions, I can run it fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command by itself `phpunit` will search in your shell's path for a PHPUnit executable. A `composer install` will place it into the composer bin dir, which is `vendor/bin` by default.  You can execute the script directly with `./vendor/bin/phpunit`, or allow composer to execute it for you, resolving the proper path for your project with `composer exec phpunit`

Comment: `composer exec phpunit`
Script phpunit handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 255